# What is my mongodb database size doubled after sharding?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, sharding

After my mongodb database grows quite a bit I decided to shard the collections.
So i created a new sharded cluster and imported my old data to the cluster using mongorestore.

`sh.status()` command shows that everything works fine as shown below [image]

However my db size doubled. Seems like instead of balancing the entire db was cloned to both shards.
[image]
[image]

The images show the result of running `db.stats()` on both old unsharded db and the new sharded one. There were no new data inserted to the new db after the restore.

Is this a bug with mongodb balancer or am I missing something?

Comment: what is the output if you actually run the same commands on the databases? My bet is your index size is huge. Do you have text indexes, or many compound indexes?

Comment: probably just a matter of reading this page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/dbStats/#dbstats-output

Comment: while restoring i dropped all the indexes @Minsky so I only have the shard key indexes and my disk usage is 8 gigs on all the cluster members where it should have been 4

Comment: can you look at the index size? it's right on db stats `db.stats()`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ermtacl

Comment: what I am failing to understand is that why my disk usage per instance did not halve @Minsky

Comment: @Minsky besides mongodb stats df command also shows that data size doesnt get reduced per instance instead doubled

Answer (score 0):

Statistics in databases are approximate and frequently delayed. When a chunk is moved from one shard to another, it is shown as existing on both shards for some time. This is probably because it does in fact exist in two places for a while.

To find out the optimal database size, insert your documents in such a way that no balancing is needed (each document is written into its final shard up front), then measure disk space usage.

To find out actual disk usage, look at disk usage instead of statistics.

Note that all databases have overhead when storing data on disk to attain better performance. In case of MongoDB this can be significant and there are various options for tuning various aspects between the server itself and WiredTiger.

Comment: My disk usage is doubled instead of halving as well @D.SM